# Economical yet reliable option to travel to IAH airport from around Houston

Tags: budget, airport-transfer, houston, iah

What are some of the economical (cheapest) yet reliable option to travel from around Houston, Texas area to IAH Georgebush Intercontinental Airport.

**Update:**
To be very exact I am looking for options from The Woodlands, Texas.

Comment: "the woodlands" is enormous, it is a city. it's difficult to see any other solution than a taxi (/uber, etc).  [google many articles on this](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g56003-i148-k2880613-Best_transportation_to_The_Woodlands-Houston_Texas.html)  it is surely well over 50 bucks for a taxi from (any part of) the woodlands, to IAH

Comment: It's almost impossible to exist without a rental car in cities like LA, Houston ... rental cars are cheap and easy; depending on your situation you may realistically have to get one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a clue as to where you are in the vast Houston area, the least expensive is by bus, the [102 Bush IAH Express](http://www.ridemetro.org/MetroPDFs/Schedules/BusSchedules/n102-Bush-IAH-Express.pdf) which runs from Travis Street at Texas Avenue to Terminal C. The cost would be less than $2.00

The very cheapest would be the free airport shuttles offered by hotels and motels in the area but, of course, you would have to have been a guest.

Shuttle and Uber will run $20-$40, again, depending on start point. [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/) can help you plan the ride.

All are reliable, but are affected by traffic conditions.

Comment: Updated the question to address starting point.

Comment: As Dorothy says ... https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Houston-Airport-IAH/The-Woodlands